# start a service in certain minutes to show the Window on screen,

Tags: android, service

//  I am new To android, I don't know how to start the Service , lets just say I   want to start it in 10 minutes, i want to show the Window on the Screen. please help.

```
public class TopWindow extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams p = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_DIALOG,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );
    // Define the position of the window within the screen
    p.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    p.x = 0;
    p.y = 100;
    final WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View popupview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_window_layout,null);
    windowManager.addView(popupview,p);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis() +60 * 1000 *10, alarmIntent);
```

[More detail on how to set alarms in android .](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms)

Make sure you have included this in the manifest for inside your service tag:-

```
 <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".ServiceClass" />
```

Comment: Will you please explain?????  I just want to poup the window .. if i am not wrong , can i do this with broadcast?

Comment: yes, you can use that too. Alarm manager allows us to schedule future task. And we use it with pending intent since these a made to work even when the app is in background. Hope this give you a little insight.

Comment: sorry for being late, will you give me the example to start the another  service in through this ? where this code should be ????

Comment: The setting of alarm manager can be done from any of your activity , which would start your service when the alarm fires.